# Count referrals from blog view to website view in social channel grouping

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Would be most grateful for any advice on this.

I have two analytics views under the same profile:

Website (mywebsite.com)
Blog (mywebsite.com/blog)

The website view excludes all traffic to the blog folder and the blog view only looks at traffic within the blog folder.

I’d like to adjust the social channel grouping on the website view to ensure any referrals from the blog to the website are counted in the social channel. I set up a regex to target referrals from mywebsite.com/blog/* however it seems any clicks from the blog are currently being counted as direct traffic (perhaps due to the filter?).

Would very much appreciate any suggested solutions / implementations to achieve this.

Many thanks!

Comment: Most probably your domain is in the referral exclusion list in the property settings/ Tracking information (It's automatically added when you set up a new GA account to avoid self-referalls).

Comment: Hi Eike, thanks for the suggestion, it sure is - however if I remove it then presumably it will open the floodgates for other self-referrals. Ideally I just want to count referrals from the blog.